# (Color) scheme for quiz/trivia/test type app/game

Tags: gui-design, interface

here is the example:

```
|   Answers  |  User Input |   Results  |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:----------:|
| (OK) A     |  selected   |   correct  | 
| (OK) B     |             |  incorrect |
| (  ) C     |             |   correct  |     
| (  ) D     |  selected   |  incorrect |
```

Really stuck on this. Use colors.

Yellow = selected, Green = correct, Red = incorrect*
But there are 2 ways to be incorrect, in this example marked as B and D:

B - not selected when you should

D - selected when you shouldn't

How is it possible, to make this simple and intuitive so that it is 
apparent how the correct answers intersect with the user answers? 
* using symbols like "V" and "X" - the problem is still the same.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. However, is this distinction really important? Usually, this kind of quizzes only require a correct/incorrect condition, watch out not to over-complicate things

Comment: I agree that the bottom line is that it's correct or incorrect. There can be a third color showing that the user hasn't selected the a response yet. This is optional but is a nice touch. I don't think you need a fourth color or anything.

Answer (score -2):

I can't figure out how really the app is supposed to work, but do you think in short phrases. I don't know, something like "oh! almost!"
In that case you have to choose an appropiate color thinking in the target users and the color palette and nothing more